# Load HTML into a DIV, but keeping the CSS,JS includes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got an index page and I want to load on a DIV another page from a very different directory, but I want that the page that will be loaded into the DIV to keep the CSS and JS includes, is it possible?

It seems that it only loads into the DIV, the body of the other page and forget the JS and CSS includes.

I'm using this code to load the HTML into the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function processAjax(url) { 

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers 
                    req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                    req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
                    try { 
                        req.open("GET", url, true); 
                        } catch (e) { 
                        alert(e); 
                    } 
                    req.send(null); 
                    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
                    if (req) { 
                        req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
                        req.open("GET", url, true); 
                        req.send(); 

                    } 
                } 
            } 

            function targetDiv() { 
                if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete 
                    if (req.status == 200) { // OK response 
                        document.getElementById("mContent").innerHTML = req.responseText; 
                        } else { 
                        alert("Problem: " + req.statusText); 
                    } 
                } 
            }  
        </script>
```

---

Usage:

```
<a href="javascript:processAjax('./DataTables/extras/Editor/treinamentos/index.html');">My Page</a>
```

Comment: believe me.. Your full code is equivalent to jquery's one line `.load()` ..

Comment: Isn't javascript faster than jQuery? Also, does jQuery method loads the includes from the target page?

Comment: jquery **is** javascript

Comment: @BernardoLima there is no meaningful performance advantage to using raw JavaScript for ajax if you're already using jQuery anyway. (If not, you should remove the "jquery" tag from the question.)

Comment: Ok, but I've asked for a function to load the included files not another function that does the same. It could be jQuery, but it has to load the target included files.

Comment: @ Mohammad Adil, jquery is not javascript, jquery is written in javascript.

Comment: @MohammadAdil What do you think that one line of jQuery code is doing? Calls the same type of code.

Comment: @Xotic750 .. Really........??

Comment: @Pointy, a performance advantage is not having to load an external library, just a thought.

Comment: @Xotic750 yes that's why I explicitly noted that there's no difference "if you're already using jQuery anyway." Using jQuery *only* for ajax might be considered wasteful, I suppose.

Comment: If he is already using jQuery the other advantage is that all included files from the loaded page also get loaded and run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use an IFRAME tag that contains the url of the page you desire to display with the js and css you want to use.

```
<iframe src="mypage.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Could be a solution, but isn't iframes a very obsolete method? Is there any new method for it that I could use?

Comment: @BernardoLima `<frame>`s are, not `<iframe>`s

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by new ?!

Comment: @Ian I'm talking about iframe ! i used it many times in similar situations

Comment: @MarouaGasmi Please read the comments. BernardoLima thought `<iframe>`s are obselete, and I pointed out that they aren't, but `<frame>`s are

Comment: @Ian yeah sorry I didn't see the obsolete part.

Comment: @MarouaGasmi, looks like 'iframe' is the best solution for now, I'm going to use it. Thank you very much, and thank you guys for all the info.